# Convert json data to newline delimited json to support BQ load using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a josn file in python cloud functions which will load into BQ in later stage.

Input json:

```
{"data": [{"DATE": "2005-10-14 00:00:00", "ID": 21.0, "NAME": "NOM"}, {"DATE": "2005-10-14 00:00:00", "ID": 22.0, "NAME": "WW"}]}
```

Expected json with newline delimiter :

```
{"DATE": "2005-10-14 00:00:00", "ID": 21.0, "NAME": "NOM"}
{"DATE": "2005-10-14 00:00:00", "ID": 22.0, "NAME": "WW"}
```

Here is sample code to achieve this

```
dat = jsondata['data']
result = [json.dumps(record) for record in dat]
for i in result:
    print(i+'\n')
```

(i+'\n') :=> correctly capturing each record but please help me to capture all the records into a string variable (by appending or update or anyother) because I will again apply `json.dumps(json_content)` to pass to another function for processing.

Comment: Do you want to convert your json into string with newlines for each record in __data__ key ? Or you want to make your json look pretty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have declared a string variable to handle my situation.

```
json_content = ""
dat = jsondata['data']
result = [json.dumps(record) for record in dat]
for i in result:
    json_content+=str(i+'\n')
```